# Can wp_get_image_editor convert to icon?

Tags: images, icon

I have a very simple question regarding **wp_get_image_editor** (https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Image_Editor). I can crop, resize and save an image like this:

```
$image = wp_get_image_editor( 'example_1.jpg' );
$image->resize( 32, 32, true );
$image->save( $path . '/test.png' ); // Works with jpg/gif/png
```

It works perfectly. I can convert a JPG file to GIF or PNG (and vice versa), but I don't seem to be able to conver an image to a .ico file. So a code like:

```
$image->save( $path . '/test.ico' );
```

Doesn't output any image nor any error/notice. So at this point I wonder: can wp_get_image_editor actually convert to .ico files (and if so, how, what am I missing/doing wrong), or it can't be done?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not 100% but I doubt you can convert to .ico

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. At least I've never saw it.

**Although** I believe that you can tailor some solution. Since WordPress 3.5 in [`WP_Image_Editor`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.4.2/src/wp-includes/class-wp-image-editor.php#L0) [is added support](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2012/12/06/wp_image_editor-is-incoming/) for Imagick by default (which is a wrapper to the [ImageMagick library](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php)). You can check [`class-wp-image-editor-imagick.php`](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) to see how it's integrated and if you have ImageMagick installed on your server, probably you can tailor something. But I believe it will probably be an overkill for a small set of .ico files.